# Ho check a <div> in another <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check if a `<div>` with a particular id is in another `<div>`. My html code is:

```
<div class="box">
    ......
    <div id="home">
    </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery code is:

```
var div=$('div[class=box]');
div.each(function(id,element){
    if($(this).find(div).length>0){
        console.log("ENTER");
    }
});
```

My purpose is to "do something" if a `<div>` with a particular class contains another `<div>` with a particular id. Anyone can help me?

Comment: `if($('div.box #home').length){}`

Comment: if($('div.box div#home').length > 0){ //do stuff }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.find('#home')` instead of `.find(div)` like following.

```
var div=$('div[class=box]');
div.each(function() {
    if($(this).find('#home').length>0){
        console.log("ENTER");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to find it, and check the length of the collection

```
if ( $('.box #home').length ) { ...
```

to find the `.box` that has the element

```
var el = $('.box:has(#home)')
```

Comment: I guess OP wants to target the `.box` containing `#home`. EDIT: after rereading question, i'm not sure...

Comment: @A.Wolff - I guess so ?

Answer (score 1):

just use a class selector (using `.`) and child selector

```
if ( $('div.box #home').length > 0 )
{
   alert( "div exists" );
}
else
{
   alert( "div doesn't exists" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($('div .box').find("div[id='home']").length > 0 ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if ($("div.box > #home").length > 0){
    console.log("ENTER");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find()` of jQuery to find your div `#home`

```
if($("div.box").find("#home").length>0){
    alert("DIV FOUND");
}
```